# Unable to set return type in ajax call for json?

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am having small trouble in ajax call i.e,unable to set data type in ajax,For string and text data types i get ajax call as success,But when i returning list from servlrt ajax call fails,Please tell me how to fix it,For any help thanks in advance.

```
 $
.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
    url : "attendancePercentage",
    dataType: "json",
    data : {"stdate": stdate, "endate": endate},
    success : function(data, status) {
        alert(status);
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Servlet:

```
    List<StudentMark> stList = new ArrayList<StudentMark>();

   try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema", "root", "root");
        String sql = "select * from attendance where attendance.date>=? and attendance.date<=?";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, stDate);
        pstmt.setString(2, enDate);

        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            StudentMark ge = new StudentMark();

            ge.setStudentName(rs.getString(3));
            ge.setDate(rs.getString(2));
            ge.setStatus(rs.getString(4));
            //System.out.println(("&&&&&..." + ge));

            stList.add(ge);
            //System.out.println("ge :" + ge.getStudentName()+","+ge.getDate()+","+ge.getStatus());

        }

        System.out.println("list>>"+stList);
        System.out.println("list>>"+json);//[{"","",""}]

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I am getting output in s.o.p statement like above ,how to set data type for this json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may override toString in StudentMarsk Class like
    @Override 
    public String toString() { 
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

Comment: can u please explain,how to do it?

Comment: import com.google.gson.Gson;
public class StudentMark {
 private String studentName;
 private String date;
 private String status;
 //your getter's and setters
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return new Gson().toJson(this);
 }
}

Comment: Tried this one ,still i am getting ajax call failure.

Comment: Also you should output using PrintWritter not to System.out 

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(stList);
response.setContentType("application/json");
out.close();

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me.can u please tell me how to get list objects in data in ajax,how to split and display.

Comment: success : function(data, status) {
  $.each(data, function(key,value) {
   alert(value.studentName);
  });
}

Comment: Thank you for all your help.can u explain the toString method how works on json